# Combining multiple row values into a single column

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I appreciate that similar questions have been asked before but I'm unsure what to try next, and am under some pressure. I'm trying to combine multiple row values into a single column, and to do this am trying to use XML Path. The following is where I have got to, but I'm now simply displaying multiple instances of multiple subjects in a single column.

Using SQL Server, I'd like to combine all subjects for a given pupil (around 10) into the 'All Subjects' column. can someone point me to where I'm going wrong? Thanks, Gavin

```
SELECT distinct
P.FORM AS Class, 
NAME.NAME AS [Pupil Name], 
(SELECT ';' + SS.DESCRIPTION
FROM PUPIL P 
INNER JOIN PUPIL_SET PS on PS.PUPIL_ID = P.PUPIL_ID
INNER JOIN SUBJECT_SET SS on SS.SUBJECT_SET_ID = PS.SUBJECT_SET_ID 
FOR XML PATH('')) [All Subjects],
NAME_1.TITLE + ' ' + NAME_1.FIRST_NAMES + ' ' + NAME_1.SURNAME AS [Parent or     Carer Name],
Replace(isnull(ADDRESS.HOUSE_STREET,'') + ', ' +     isnull(ADDRESS.VILLAGE_AREA,'') + ', ' + isnull(ADDRESS.TOWN_CITY,'') + ', ' +     isnull(ADDRESS.COUNTY,'') + ', ' + isnull(ADDRESS.COUNTRY,'') + ' ' +     isnull(ADDRESS.POST_CODE,''),',,', '') AS Address,
--RELATIONSHIP.RANK,
CASE WHEN NAME.MAIN_ADDRESS_ID = NAME_1.MAIN_ADDRESS_ID THEN 'HOME' ELSE    'OTHER' END AS [Home or Other]
FROM PUPIL P
INNER JOIN NAME ON P.NAME_ID = NAME.NAME_ID
INNER JOIN ADDRESS ON NAME.MAIN_ADDRESS_ID = ADDRESS.ADDRESS_ID
INNER JOIN RELATIONSHIP ON NAME.NAME_ID = RELATIONSHIP.FROM_NAME_ID
INNER JOIN NAME AS NAME_1 ON RELATIONSHIP.TO_NAME_ID = NAME_1.NAME_ID
INNER JOIN PUPIL_SET PS on PS.PUPIL_ID = P.PUPIL_ID
INNER JOIN SUBJECT_SET SS on SS.SUBJECT_SET_ID = PS.SUBJECT_SET_ID
WHERE 
(RELATIONSHIP.RANK=1 Or RELATIONSHIP.RANK=2) 
AND P.ACADEMIC_YEAR=YEAR(DateAdd(m,-5,getDate()))
AND P.SUB_SCHOOL='030SEN' 
AND P.IN_USE='y' 
AND P.RECORD_TYPE='1' 
AND Len(P.FORM)>0
and p.ACADEMIC_YEAR = 2015;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you only need `subject_set` and `pupil_set` in the subquery, not the outer query.

Second, you need a correlation clause.  So, something like this:

```
SELECT P.FORM AS Class,
       . . .
       (SELECT ';' + SS.DESCRIPTION
        FROM PUPIL_SET PS INNER JOIN
             SUBJECT_SET SS
             on SS.SUBJECT_SET_ID = PS.SUBJECT_SET_ID 
        WHERE PS.PUPIL_ID = P.PUPIL_ID
        FOR XML PATH('')
       ) [All Subjects],
       . . .
FROM PUPIL P INNER JOIN
     NAME
     ON P.NAME_ID = NAME.NAME_ID INNER JOIN
     ADDRESS
     ON NAME.MAIN_ADDRESS_ID = ADDRESS.ADDRESS_ID INNER JOIN
     RELATIONSHIP
     ON NAME.NAME_ID = RELATIONSHIP.FROM_NAME_ID INNER JOIN
     NAME AS NAME_1
     ON RELATIONSHIP.TO_NAME_ID = NAME_1.NAME_ID
WHERE  . . .;
```

You should not need `SELECT DISTINCT`.  You were getting duplicates because of the unnecessary joins.